# retrieving unknown parent node from known child key node in realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure:

[image]

**Instructions:**

- User 1, 2, and 3 can **only** be available in either nodes: ketchup,
  mayo, **or** ranch.
- Child nodes ketchup, mayo, and ranch are unknown and My point of access is the node **reference**.
- Knowing my *super child* or *my grand child* key: user 1,

how can I retrieve if user 1 is under ketchup, mayo, or ranch?

Current code:

```
databaseHelper.getUserEndPoint("reference").orderByChild("user 1")

    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            String parent = dataSnapshot.getRef().getParent().toString();
            Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: dataSnapshot exists");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

I have a solution that I'm not really proud of :/. The **non desired** solution is to loop through children of my reference, that are (ketchup, mayo, and ranch), and then look within each of these meta data for user 1. I believe that this solution is pretty time complexed.

Comment: You may want to consider duplicating your data into a different structure that makes this query easier.  This is common in nosql databases, as not all structures are helpful for all intended queries.

Comment: In android, is it possible to use a wildcard and pass it to the reference and then retrieve the parent when the key “user 1” is found?

Comment: No, there are no wildcards in references.